# How to compile C code into R?

Tags: c, r, dll, compilation

I am trying to modify an R package that works with C and Fortran code, so in order to test my modifications im trying to compile this C code in R. I have never worked before with C so I am following the steps described at this website: http://mcglinn.web.unc.edu/blog/linking-c-with-r-in-windows/

I have completed all the steps: Downloaded Rtools, modified the PATH, created the C file with some functions and compiled it. The .dll file has been correctly generated (seems so). But when I try to load this code into R using dyn.load I get the following error:

```
dyn.load("sequence_examples.dll")

Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/alvaromc317/ZZ_ALVARO/sequence_examples.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I am not sure what is going wrong. My system works with an x64 architecture, so I installed R and Rtools x64 versions.

Comment: Did you modify PATH to contain the 64-bit R?

Comment: Yes, I did. This is what I added to the PATH referred to R: C:\Users\alvaromc317\R\R-3.4.2\bin\i386

Comment: This points to the 32-bit R. I guess a \x64 directory is needed